# Confused with flow of control in program

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am using Parse database in my android application. I am puzzled with the way control is flowing in my program `ConnectDatabse.java`. Here is the code:

```
public class ConnectDatabase extends Activity {
    public static int LOGIN_STATUS;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    public static boolean authenticate(Context c, String email, String password) {
        Log.d("Message", email+" & "+password);
        Parse.initialize(c, "IFm3T3f7445F8fRILTcO", "HTwH2gycHQMS7LpyAf43mud");
        ParseUser.logInInBackground(email, password, new LogInCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("Inside done", "Msg: " + e);
            if (user != null) {
                 LOGIN_STATUS = 1;
                 Log.d("LOGIN_STATUS value", Integer.toString(LOGIN_STATUS));
            } 
            else {
                 LOGIN_STATUS = 0;
            }
        }
        });
        Log.d("After done(..)" , Integer.toString(LOGIN_STATUS));
        if(LOGIN_STATUS == 1) return true;
        else return false;       

        }
    }
```

My `LoginActivity.java` code is :

```
public void login(View v) {
        AutoCompleteTextView emailInput = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
        EditText passwordInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        String email = emailInput.getText().toString();
        String password = passwordInput.getText().toString();
        if(ConnectDatabase.authenticate(this, email, password) == true) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
        else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Unsuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
```

In the logcat window, it first displays "Message" Tag, then "After done(..)", then "Inside done" followed by "LOGIN_STATUS value" = 1

Comment: you need to understand what an **asynchronous method** is

Comment: http://ideone.com/yVZP3Q

Answer (score 1):

You've asked for a task to be done in the background, so your program will continue executing the rest while that task is done in the background. You probably want some sort of listener or callback method that you can call when your task is done to do other tasks if you need to rely on something being done before a certain piece of code is executed.

Comment: Alright. In my case I am calling authenticate(..) method in Activity, so it will obviously expect return value from same method. done() method wont let me return anything, so how do I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution in the documentation of parse API. Here is my final `ConnectDatabase.java` :

```
public static boolean authenticate(Context c, String email, String password) throws ParseException {
        Log.d("Message", email+" & "+password);
        Parse.initialize(c, "IFmI83T3f7445F8fRILTcO", "HTwH2gycHQMSDvLpyAf43mud");
        ParseUser.logIn(email, password);
        return true;
        }
```

and in `LoginActivity.java` I caught the ParseException which will be thrown if the user is not found or there is a network error.